# ElasticSearch Nodejs Express Automated Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, express, elasticsearch

How to implement automated test for ElasticSearch using Node testing framework?

I want to implement ElasticSearch into my nodejs Project for efficient searching abilities, which is using Express framework , frisby, Socket.io etc. ElasticSearch nodejs implementation is easily available on google but not it's automation testing. Need Suggestions.

Comment: I found a solution for this,  previously, i used the Mysql database instead of ElasticSearch and wrote functional test cases according to Mysql database. Now when I replaced the Mysql with ElasticSearch, the written test cases should not be fail. I thought that this will be the procedure for testing the elasticsearch that it will not effected our system and it assure that it is correctly implemented

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) or [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) as testing frameworks for Node.js. Within the test suites you can use another library: [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

Superagent allows you to perform HTTP requests to a specified url.

On the other hand you have an elasticsearch that receives HTTP requests.

You can have a library of data sets in the form of http requests to issue towards elasticsearch. Each data set will be suitable to feed elasticsearch to check wether or not a test passes or fails.

Here is an example of how superagent can be used to issue a request to an elasticsearch server:

```
var request = require('superagent');
var should = require('should.js');

describe('Your test suite', function () {
    it('Should test elasticsearch search', function (done) {
      request.get('http://localhost:9002/index/type/_search')
        .end(function (err, res) {
          should.not.exist(err);
          should.exist(res);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can do the samething using frisby which i have already integrated.

Comment: Yes, didn't notice you have frisby available. The methodology is still valid though.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but as you posted the question you can accept the answer by clicking the tick below the upvote/downvote. This acceptance  show other users that the answer is valid for you